# How long can I expect to wait for a 20 gwei ERC20 launch?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, gas, gas-price

Here's the transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9e34257bbb18e565a2154eb522085a30720e327b065342b5708c089d23e190cb

I'm spending 20 gwei per unit of gas. This is all I could afford, I only have 10 dollars in ether. How long will it take for this token to launch? I'm new to crypto, so **will I have to pay this much every time I transfer crypto**? Thanks!

**Edit:** Thanks for the response, I put in bold the most important part of the question. also, I was just wondering if 20gwei was reasonable, or it would be worth the money to increase the gas price.

Answer (score 2):

transaction fee is constant, and it just changes (decreases) if you are not in hurry and can wait for the network to be a little less crowded (some wallets have this option, not all of them). but if you want to send/receive in the exact time the next block is mined, then you have to pay the constant miner fee, which is different for each crypto.

and you have to note that exchange sites/wallets which give you the crypto you buy instantly, DOES NOT transfer the crypto to your address. they have the crypto in their own address, and tell/show you that you own the amount you bought from them. are we clear?